# is there a livejournal URL that expands all comments for a particular page?

Tags: comments

For example, I want to open the URL

```
http://XXX.livejournal.com/NNN.html?page=1
```

where there will be no links like

```
"...and 36 more comments..."
```

Is there some parameter, that I can pass to livejournal? Something like

```
http://XXX.livejournal.com/NNN.html?page=1&COMMENTS=SHOWALL
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like it cannot be changed. The [livejournal FAQ says](http://www.livejournal.com/support/faq/62.html)

> Collapsed Threads: With 25+ comments on a page, the comment threads
>   will collapse, so lower-level child comments display as a link rather
>   than the full comment; this automatic behavior cannot be prevented.